# Num and Integral type classes - Haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I am reading Type classes, [Chapter 2 of Learn You Haskell For Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses#typeclasses-101). My question is why 4 + 3.2 works but not length [1, 2, 3, 4] + 3.2, why do we need to use *fromIntegral* function in second case. Is there no relation between *Num* and *Integral* type classes. How do I find what classes a type is instance of ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In cases like this use ghci to check the types, for example it will tell you for your first input:

```
Prelude> :t 4 + 3.2
4 + 3.2 :: Fractional a => a
```

here the `fromInteger` is implicit (the `4`) used.

In the second case you have the problem, that `length` is `:: [a] -> Int` (a bit different in newer GHCs) and `3.2` is still `:: Fractional a => a` but `(+)` is `:: Num a => a -> a -> a` (it needs the same type of parameters `a`) - now `Int` is not an instance of `Fractional` and you get the error.

---

### How to find the classes a type is instance of

PS (the original answer to that is gone) - the easiest way is using GHCi using `:i` itself:

```
Prelude> :i Int
data Int = GHC.Types.I# GHC.Prim.Int#   -- Defined in ‘GHC.Types’
instance Bounded Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Enum’
instance Enum Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Enum’
instance Eq Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
instance Integral Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance Num Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
instance Ord Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
instance Read Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Read’
instance Real Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance Show Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
```

but please remember that this will depend on the loaded modules - for example when you `import Test.QuickCheck` you will see that `Int` now instance of `Arbitrary` too:

```
Prelude Test.QuickCheck> :i Int
data Int = GHC.Types.I# GHC.Prim.Int#   -- Defined in ‘GHC.Types’
instance Bounded Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Enum’
instance Enum Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Enum’
instance Eq Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
instance Integral Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance Num Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
instance Ord Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
instance Read Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Read’
instance Real Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance Show Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
instance [overlap ok] [safe] CoArbitrary Int
  -- Defined in ‘Test.QuickCheck.Arbitrary’
instance [overlap ok] [safe] Arbitrary Int
  -- Defined in ‘Test.QuickCheck.Arbitrary’
```

Answer (score 0):

`length` fixes its output type as `Int` (which is incompatible with `3.2`) rather than any `Num`. The function you are looking for is:

```
genericLength :: Num i => [b] -> i
```